# How to make a way for a textfield to populate the CORRECT host ip address when the JCombobox selects the SID on NETBEANS

Tags: java, oracle, jcombobox, tnsnames

I am having difficulty trying to get the tnsname.ora file to do the following:

```
I managed to get the JComboBox populated with the data from the service_name

My next question is the following:
```

a. How does one populate the CORRECT/appropriate host name (e.g. 127.0.0.3) if the specific service_name is selected on the JCombobox.

i. I know this can be done using a itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie), and I can make it action so populates data whenever one selects a different service name. But the question is HOW or WHAT WAY can one do to do the following:

```
If the service_name equals a certain SID
```

a. Then go and get populate the textboxes which store:

i. Host

ii. Port

iii. Protocol

I have my own theory how this could be done but do not know how to translate this to Java code:

- If the service_name is selected
- Go to previous line (4 steps back) where host details is populated
  -> Populate the host data to the host textbox
- Go to the previous line where the port is populated
  -> Populate the port data to port textbox

---

```
public void PopulateTnsNamesDropDownList() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();

    InputStream input2 = null;

    try {
        input2 = new FileInputStream("C:\\folder\\config.properties");

        try {
            prop.load(input2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String path = null;
        path = prop.getProperty("tnsnames_directory");

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            String line = null;

            try {
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.contains("(SERVICE_NAME =")) {
                        String service_name = null;
                        service_name = line.replaceAll("SERVICE_NAME = ", "").trim().replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)", "");

                        strings.add(service_name);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, "Error, configuration properties did not exist or not set correctly." + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        finally {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, "Error, configuration properties did not exist or not set correctly." + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        String[] lineArray = strings.toArray(new String[] {});
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(lineArray);
        TnsNamesComboBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(lineArray));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, "Error, configuration properties did not exist or not set correctly." + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the code where you populate host, port and protocol?

Comment: you added the code where you populate the service names, not the host, port and protocol. my suggestion would be to write a seperate class that does nothing but parsing the tnsnames.ora. It should create (for example) create a `HashMap` with the service name as key an an ArrayList with the other info as the value.

Comment: take a look at this TNS Parser example: http://oraclescripts.blogspot.de/2005/01/java-tns-parser-api.html Maybe that helps you.